# Laplace transform of "nested" convolutions

Tags: laplace-transform

In my studies, I stumbled across the following:
$$p(t) = f(t) + f(t) * g(t) + f(t) * g(t) * g(t) + f(t) * g(t) * g(t) * g(t) ...$$
where the Laplace transform of f(t) and g(t) is known, * is the convolution of the listed functions:
$$ \int_0^t{f(t)g(t-s)ds} $$

Can I also write the function p after Laplace transform like this?
$$ P(s) = F(s) + F(s)G(s) + F(s)G(s)G(s) + F(s)G(s)G(s)G(s)+ \cdots$$
Hence:
$$ P(s) = F(s)G(s)^0 + F(s)G(s)^1 + F(s)G(s)^2 + F(s)G(s)^3+ \cdots$$
So:
$$ P(s) = F(s)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{G(s)^n} $$

Or is this an unqualified simplification?
Thanks

Comment: Yes, you are right. This follows from the fact that convolution is associative.

Comment: You are correct. If $|G(s)| < 1$ $\forall s$ $-$ which is quite necessary, otherwise the sum will be divergent $-$, you can event write $P(s) = \frac{F(s)}{1-G(s)}$.

Comment: @Julian thank you; I was just confused, cause wolfram alpha was giving a strange solution for "laplace transform $\int_0^{oo}\int_0^{oo}{f(x)g(y)g(t-y-x)dx dy}$" --> $F(s)\int_0^{oo}{g(y)g(t-y) dy}$

Comment: @Abezhiko thank you, being that $G(s) = e^{-\sqrt{s}}$, the series converges for $s > 0$. Is it then correct to write $P(s) = \begin{matrix}\{ s = 0; F(s)\sum_{n=0}^{00} \\ s > 0;\frac{F(s)}{(1-G(s))}\end{matrix}$?